# Multiple conditions in for statement

Tags: c++, for-loop

I have this code in a function, but when it runs it does a long pause and then it says:

```
$floating point exception
```

I am assuming this is due to multiple conditions in the for loop, but I don't know why it is wrong. Any ideas?

```
int i,j,number=5;
for (i = 2; (i < number || j==1); i++)
{
    if (number%i==0)
    {
        j = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the *types* of `i`, `j`, and `number`?

Comment: Post a minimal compilable example that reproduces the error!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**floating point exception** - This means there's an arithmetic error.

It looks like you're trying to stop the loop with j, but what you're actually doing is continuing the loop forever (because once you get **j==1** the `or` condition is always **true**).
What then happens is you loop **i** through all the **Integer** values back to **0** and get the exception.

What I think you want to do is :

```
for (i = 2; (i < number); i++)
{
    if (number%i==0)
    {
        j = 1;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @EO You don't have to use the **Break**, you could change the loop condition (but i think it's less expressive of the intention): `for (i = 2, j=0; (i < number && j!=1); i++)`

Answer (score 2):

Remember that the condition is for the loop to *continue*, not for it to end.

It's difficult to look at your code and see intuitively what you're trying to do. Although you could fix this by flipping some logic around (you meant `(i < number && j != 1)`), it's best to stop and use `break` inside the loop instead. The logic will be *far* clearer, and then you won't make errors like this.

Answer (score 1):

Once you set `j` to 1 the loop will go on forever. If you want to stop the loop when the `if` condition is true use `break`.

Answer (score 0):

You will get into an infinite loop when the `if`-statement is reached. This will cause the error. You probably wanted to stop the loop if `j == 1`? Then you had to write

```
for (i = 2; (i < number || j!=1); i++)
```