# The credibility of the break statement

Tags: c++, break

I had recently read in a book that using the `break` statement in say e.g. `for` loops is considered inelegant (although it is widely accepted for use in the `switch` statement).

What is the reason for this "accusation"?

Should I use a `break` statement in a `for` loop, or should I use multiple conditions?

Comment: I bet the same book would advise that each function have exactly one return statement. Ridiculous

Comment: Can you add a context where it's considered 'inelegant'? I don't think they say that about all loops.

Comment: @Emile: Could you tell us which book this is? I'm curious.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Break statements In the real world](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216359/break-statements-in-the-real-world)

Comment: Or, the book does not say not to use break statements, but its says that some people think that it is un-elegant to use them (the book does not neccesarily agree). The book is from Deitel How to Program C++ 5/e (i know its kinda old, hey :D)

Comment: @Tomalak, don't questions have to be more than 3 days old to be taken into account? Anyway, perhaps a better discussion for meta anyway. Update, see here: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/new-question-asker-features/

Comment: @Emile: The word is "inelegant".

Comment: @Emile: You are not "the establishment", and you are not able to edit/remove my comments since you are not a moderator. Thus I was not referring to you. :)

Comment: @Tomalak Oh :P, (googled establishment, and figured out it meant "the staff and equipment of a commercial or other organization " so edited my comment to only thanks)

Comment: Personally I have no problem using break. But there were quite a lot debate about 'break' in this link.

Break statements In the real world

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan is it sarcasm or do you really think multiple `return`'s are good?

Comment: @RocketR: I do believe that in some cases multiple returns make the code simpler and more readable. And don't tell me about RVO :)

Comment: No, my argument is that it generates destructor calls on each `return` making the code bigger.

Comment: @RocketR: Am I hearing premature microoptimizations?

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan 'Avoiding premature optimization' != 'Writing the most inefficient code'. You wouldn't call passing parameters by const-reference a premature microoptimization, would you?

Comment: @RocketR: No, I wouldn't. I think we're just drawing the line at different places.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll have to ask the author of the book (*which* book?), since my ESP is on the fritz today<sup>*[citation needed]*</sup>.

Sometimes<sup>*[when?]*</sup> it's said that, if you write lots of `break` statements throughout your code body, then it's no longer easy to see the loop invariants and the control flow without performing a detailed program analysis.

But, realistically, a couple of `break` statements inside conditional blocks isn't going to hurt anyone, and complicating loop conditionals is, IMO, more immediately prone to [going horribly wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6719238/multiple-conditions-in-for-statement).

Answer (score 1):

The reasoning is that it's clearer to have the condition for continuing or exiting the loop  in one place rather than scattered throughout the body of the loop.

Comment: I don't see how is that any clearer.. seems more *complicated*. break does what it says. if you read the equivalent multi-conditional code you both have to understand the condition in the for loop and the meaning of the variable assignment.

Answer (score 1):

This is like those who say `goto` is bad because of a paper Djikstra wrote on the subject in the 60's.  When used liberally, I would agree.  But for instance, in a C-function, which doesn't have the benefit of C++'s exception handling using `try` and `catch`, the deliberate and intentional use of `goto` can be very helpful in creating a self-contained clean-up section in case of an error return for a function that allocates memory using `malloc()`.  Without the `goto` statement, you would have to place clean-up code at the end of every `if` statement that detected an error.  For instance, what looks better to you ... this:

```
int my_func()
{
    int* a = malloc(10);

    //... some code
    if (some_error)
    {
        free(a);
        return -1;
    }

    //... more code

    if (some_other_error)
    {
        free(a);
        return -1;
    }

    //... more code

    if (another_error)
    {
        free(a);
        return -1;
    }

    //... more code

    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

or code that looks like this:

```
void my_func()
{
    int* a = malloc(10);

    //... some code

    if (some_error)
        goto return_error;

    //... more code

    if (some_other_error)
        goto return_error;

    //... more code

    if (another_error)
        goto return_error;

    //... more code

    normal_return:
        free(a);
        return 0;

    return_error:
        free(a);
        return -1;
}
```

With the first example, every time you changed something, you would have to manage all the error returns in each of the if-statement blocks.  The latter approach gives you a nice self-contained clean-up section.  So the same is true with other arbitrary rules for syntax like "don't use `break` in a loop" ... if it helps increase the code's maintainability, reliability, and readability, by all means use it.

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of style.
There would be people who say it breaks the flow of the loop ( Just like you shouldn't use multiple return statements in a method).

But a `break` is very expressive. Properly placed breaks can be much more readable and maintainable than a loop condition that includes the state in which we should stop the loop (instead of the breaks).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it helps, but, Joaquín M López Muñoz addressed this question in his blog:
http://bannalia.blogspot.com/2009/03/about-break-statements.html

Regards,
&rzej