# Complex condition in FOR loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if it's possible to state 2 statements as a FOR loop's condition in JavaScript.

```
for (var i = 0; i < x.length || 10; i++) {

}
```

instead of writing

```
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if(i<10) {

    }
}
```

**Used references** (didn't help too much):

[Multiple conditions in for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19546312/multiple-conditions-in-for-loop)

[Multiple conditions in for statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6719238/multiple-conditions-in-for-statement)

Comment: Visit this link http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

Comment: @choxx I know how FOR works, I was just wondering if it's possible to do it in the way I asked.

Comment: GUYS, the question wasnt about how a for loop works.. please keep in mind when downvoting.

Comment: Well then you must also know the code you wrote in Ist part doesn't make any sense..

Comment: You can't directly write **i < x.length || 10;** If you are assigning multiple conditions in FOR, then you must have to follow the coding rules as per standard. **i < x.length || i < 10;**

Comment: @choxx ofc it didn't, I had no idea of the proper way of defining. 
dystroy's solution works just as I wanted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the goal is to end the loop when `i` reaches `10` or `i` reaches the end of the array, you may write it like this :

```
for (var i=0; i<x.length && i<10; i++) {
```

In that case you might also compose it like this

```
for (var i=0; i<Math.min(x.length,10); i++) {
```

or for better performances :

```
for (var i=0, n=Math.min(x.length,10); i<n; i++) {
```

Comment: isn't it possible in the simple way as I wrote it? like i < x.length || 10;

Comment: @KissKoppány no, this writing makes no sense

Comment: No it isnt possible this way

Comment: @MoisheLipsker No, you'd need to use `&&`. Otherwise, if `x.length` is smaller than 10 you'll go out of bounds.

Comment: @dystroy your solution is nice and kind of what I was looking for: `for (var i=0; i<Math.min(x.length,10); i++) {` Nice and clear.

Comment: @KissKoppány take a look at paolo answer. It explains what you wrote. 
Basically 10 is always 10 it is not a condition. i == 10 is a condition and so it i < 10

Comment: @dystroy well, it actually have a sense or at least is valid javascript. Of course not fuctionally equivalent to the second code snippet.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not in the syntax of the `for` loop but in the way you put the conditional stetement:

```
i < x.length || 10
```

evaluates as

```
(i < x.length) || 10
```

that evaluates as

```
true || 10
```

or

```
false || 10
```

depending on the value of `i` and the length of `x`

The first will then result in `true` while the latter in `10`.

So the `for` loop goes on forever and is not equivalent to the second code snipped you posted.

The above is to explain why the two code snippets you posted are not functionally equivalent.

The correct statement is

```
for (var i=0; i<x.length && i<10; i++) {
```

or one of the other proposed in **dystroy**'s excellent answer.